# Cannot use class in NSSet<TKey>

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I'm attempting to create a binding for an iOS Framework for Xamarin and it's stumbling on the generic type for some NSSet properties:

```
// @interface Foo : NSObject
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface Foo
{ ... }

// @interface Bar : NSObject
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
interface Bar
{
    // @property (readonly, nonatomic) NSSet<Foo *> * _Nonnull foos;
    [Export("foos")]
    NSSet<Foo> foos { get; }
}
```

Produces the error

> Error CS0311: The type 'Namespace.Foo' cannot be used as type parameter 'TKey' in the generic type or method 'NSSet'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Namespace.Foo' to 'ObjCRuntime.INativeObject'.

I don't understand the error because the `Foo` class is based on NSObject, why is this error being produced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Foundation.NSSet<TKey> Class`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.NSSet%3CTKey%3E/) is declared as

```cs
[Foundation.Register("NSSet", SkipRegistration=true)]
public sealed class NSSet<TKey> : NSSet, IEnumerable<TKey>
    where TKey : class, INativeObject
```

I.e., your concrete `TKey` must be a class implementing `INativeObject`. `Foo` does not. If you change `Foo` to

```cs
interface Foo : INativeObject
{ }
```

... the compiler error disappears.

---

`where TKey : class, INativeObject` is a [(generic) Type Parameter Constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters). It tells you that the type argument for `TKey` must be a reference type through the `class` keyword and that it must implement the interface `INativeObject`.

Comment: I just figured this out, doing that does fix the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`NSSet<TKey>` is defined as:

```
public sealed class NSSet<TKey> : NSSet, IEnumerable<TKey>
    where TKey : class, INativeObject
```

re: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/bc492585d137d8c3d3a2ffc827db3cdaae3cc869/src/Foundation/NSSet_1.cs#L37

Supply an iOS native type as Foo does not satisfy the generic constraint.

At a minimum you can use **`NSSet<NSObject>`** or if you know the actual set types you will be using (or if you need to create helper properties/methods) use the most refined object type that you can `NSSet<NSString>`, `NSSet<CGRect>`, etc...